# AWS API Gateway - how to remove HTTP->HTTPS redirect for Edge endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I am using custom domain name in my API Gateway and currently, all http calls are redirected to https. I would like to change it, so the cloudfront returns 403 (Forbidden) on http calls.

In all discussions about this topic, I see a suggestion to edit my Cloudfront distribution, change "Viewer Protocol Policy" setting to "HTTPS only". The problem is that **I have no CloudFront distribution deployed, my endpoints are of "Edge" type** so I guess that some default cloudfront distributions are used, the ones I cant edit. I would like to ask - is there a way to keep my custom domain names with "Edge" type and, at the same type, disable http calls on them? And if yes, how? Thank you.

EDIT: My current setup: when I display my APIs through API Gateway, I see that all of them have the endpoint type "Edge". Also when I open my "Custom domain name", in the Endpoint configuration, I see it has the endpoint type "Edge".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Edge type for API Gateway, [AWS uses its own regional CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/). You have **no control** over it.

> This type of endpoint acts like a regional endpoint, but has an **AWS managed CloudFront** web distribution in front of it to help improve the client connection time.

If you want to be able to change the settings of your CloudFront distro, you have to create **your own distribution**, as explained in:

- [How do I set up API Gateway with my own CloudFront distribution?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/)

> I want an **edge-optimized API endpoint** in Amazon API Gateway, but I need **more control** over the Amazon CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I understand it correctly, if I already have 10 APIs assigned to my custom domain name, I have to edit them one by one and switch them to Regional type? I cannot just somehow link my custom domain name to my custom Cloudfront distribution?

Comment: @Jozef No problem. If you setup your own CF distro, its fully independent from API gateway. So you have to configure it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, but still not sure at which level should I use that Regional endpoint. Both all APIs and Custom Domain Name will need to have Regional endpoint type or one of them can stay Edge?

Comment: @Jozef Sorry, I'm not sure I understated your current setup. Could you maybe update the question with your configurations?

Comment: Of course - done. What is still confusing me that when I check my APIs, all have Endpoint type "Edge". And my custom domain name has Endpoint type "Edge" as well

Comment: @Jozef Have you tried migrading edge to regional domain as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-migrate.html)?